# Gender detection in python

Tags: python-2.7, export-to-csv

I want to do gender detection for a data in a csv file that has names
the following is the code i have used

```
import csv
import urllib2
import json
c = csv.reader(open("names.csv"))
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen<"https://gender-api.com/get?name=",c>)
name=csv.writer(open("c")+print "GENDER:")
```

I am getting this error: `TypeError: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()`. please correct me on this.

Comment: Have you tried running the codes? Any errors?

Comment: TypeError: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len() is the error i get while   data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen<"https://gender-api.com/get?name=",c>) it is being executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a `csv.reader` from a data file but you skipped the step of reading the file's rows. You'll need to iterate through its rows, extract the relevant column(s), and pass them each to your network service.

See [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for info and an example.

I suggest breaking this down into small parts and getting part to work, one by one:

- First just write the csv reading code and make that work, printing each input name to the console. Don't try to do the rest until this part works.
- Then extract the desired csv column, and again print those values.
- Then add the network request code and make that work, printing the JSON text. (What's with the angle brackets in your code `urlopen<...>`? That's not Python.)
- Then make the JSON conversion work, printing the parsed JSON object.
- Then extract the relevant part of each JSON object, and print those to the console.
- Then make the `csv.writer` work.

In short, every part of your code needs fixing, and the successful approach is to do it incrementally.